# Nested Dropdown in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the sheet 'Dropdowns' I have the first column "Module" pulling from a range of headers on the sheet 'Values' =Values!$A$1:$L$1. Once an option in A2 is selected in the dropdown in the Module column, I need B2 to show the options under the matching column header in the Values sheet.

For example if Asset_Top is selected I need B2 to show a dropdown of:

- asset_top__eyebrow__value
- asset_top__title__value
- asset_top__description__value

if Prize is selected then next cell over in column B should display a dropdown of:

- prize__eyebrow__value
- prize__title__value
- prize__description__value
- prize__body_copy__value
- prize__bottom_copy__value

How can I get this to work? I need to have 30 rows of options in the sheet 'Dropdown'
Here is a link to google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YrD1mCDzQ5RAG6GSQTufAv5ysvxW9JhlanpcsMu0GiM/edit#gid=1428585113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.rowStart != 2) return;     // stop if not row 2
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1) return;  // stop if not column 1
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();         
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Dropdowns') return; // stop if not 'Dropdown' sheet

  var ss = e.source;

  // get the header and all the rest rows from the sheet 'Values'
  var [header, ...data] = ss.getSheetByName('Values').getDataRange().getValues();

  // convert columns into object {header1:col1, header2:col2, ...etc}
  var obj = {};
  header.forEach((x,i) => obj[x] = data.map(x => x[i]).filter(String));

  // get the column with given header from the object
  var list = obj[e.value];

  // create data validation from the 'list'
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();

  // set data validation for the cell 'B1'
  // and put the first element of the list into the cell;
  sheet.getRange('b2').setDataValidation(rule).setValue(list[0]);
}
```

**Update**

Here is the code to handle the range A3:B30:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1) return;
  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  if (row < 3 || row > 30) return;
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Dropdowns') return;
  var ss = e.source;
  var [header, ...data] = ss.getSheetByName('Values').getDataRange().getValues();
  var obj = {};
  header.forEach((x,i) => obj[x] = data.map(x => x[i]).filter(String));
  var list = obj[e.value]
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();
  sheet.getRange(row,2).setDataValidation(rule).setValue(list[0]);
}
```

[image]

**Update 2**

Here is the variant of the code that works with range C2:D30 on sheets 'Dropdowns' and 'More_Dropdowns':

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (col != 3) return; // column C

  var row = e.range.rowStart;
  if (row < 2 || row > 30) return; // rows from 2 to 30

  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheets = ['Dropdowns', 'More_Dropdowns']; // sheets to watch
  if (!sheets.includes(sheet.getName())) return;

  var ss = e.source;
  var [header, ...data] = ss.getSheetByName('Values').getDataRange().getValues();
  var obj = {};
  header.forEach((x,i) => obj[x] = data.map(x => x[i]).filter(String));
  var list = obj[e.value]
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).build();
  sheet.getRange(row,col+1).setDataValidation(rule).setValue(list[0]);
}
```

Comment: I added that to the app scripts, it works for cell A2 and B2, however how can I get it to work for rows A3 down to A30 and B30, thx.

Comment: I just added the solution for 30 rows.

Comment: thx this worked. If I want to have module and options as column C and D and have them in other sheets for example, in tab 'Dropdowns' and 'More_Dropdowns'. here is a link to updated sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YrD1mCDzQ5RAG6GSQTufAv5ysvxW9JhlanpcsMu0GiM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've added second update. It should works with new range and the two sheets.